# Ruby: Issue with Recursive Function that Should Return Array of Max Values from Sub-arrays

Tags: ruby, recursion, arrayofarrays

The following function is designed to take in an array of arrays and return the maximum values of its sub arrays.

```
def temp(list)
  if list.all? { |i| i.kind_of?(Array) }
    return(list.each { |j| j.max })
  else
    return(list)
  end
end
```

So given a list and function call like this:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

temp(x)
```

It should return [2, 4], but instead it just returns the original array [[1, 2], [3, 4]]. I would like to know what's going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: We could even further simplify this to `list.map { |each| [*each].max }` if they are cool with processing mixed arrays. Which I assume they might be.

Answer (score 3):

`each` operates on each element of an array and then returns the (original) array. The method you want is `map`:

```
def temp(list)
  if list.all? {|i| i.kind_of?(Array) }
    list.map {|j| j.max }
  else
    list
  end
end

x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
temp(x)
# => [2, 4]
```

However, explicit type checking isn't idiomatic in Ruby, which prefers duck typing. Don't check if `i` is an Array; just check if it responds to `max`:

```
def temp(list)
  return list unless list.all? {|i| i.respond_to?(:max) }
  list.map(&:max)
end
```

Comment: You could also do  `list.map { |l| l.send ( l.respond_to?(:max) ? :max : :itself ) }` to allow for intermixed arrays and scalars at the same level.

Comment: @MarkReed Or `list.map {|l| l.respond_to?(:max) ? l.max : l }`. 

Comment: You can use `list.map { |l| [*l].max }` if we loosen up the `all?` requirement anyway.

Comment: Nah, far too clear.  How bout `list.map { |l| l.send %i{max itself}.find {|s| l.respond_to? s}}` ;-)

Comment: `public_send` is preferred to `send`, no ?

Answer (score 1):

If you loosen up the `all?` requirement, then…

Try this

```
def temp(list)
  list.map { |l| Array(l).max }
end
```

How does this work?

- `Array(l)` turns arrays into arrays
- and turns other objects into single element arrays
- and turns `nil` into an empty array
- hence we can always call `max`

Comment: You should generally prefer `Array(l)`, which involves virtually no overheard, over `[*l]` which is an extremely expensive way to convert an array into itself, functionally a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the list itself after running the code block on each member of the list. Instead, you could create another list inside the function and push the `max` values inside that list, returning it.

```
def temp(list)
  if list.all? { |i| i.kind_of?(Array) }
    maxlist=[]
    list.each { |j| maxlist << j.max }
    return maxlist
  else
    return(list)
  end
end

x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

puts temp(x)
```

That will output 2 and 4 as expected.

Comment: It's very unidiomatic to initialize an empty list and then use `each` to append to it. `map` is what you should be using here.

Comment: @meagar Sure! I'm still not very experienced with Ruby and only remembered of that method after reading Jordan's answer. Didn't think it was fair to edit mine after it!